# Laravel dependency injection Auth::

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a laravel project with a CalendarService and I inject that service into my controller. In the constructer I do something like this:

CalendarService.php

```
/** @var Collection|Timelog[] */
private $timelogs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->currentRoute = URL::to( '/' ) . "/home";
    $this->timelogs     = Auth::user()->timelogs()->get();
    $this->currentDay   = 0;
}
```

HomeController.php

```
/** @var CalendarService */
protected $calenderService;

public function __construct
(
    CalendarService $calendarService
)
{
    $this->calenderService = $calendarService;
}
```

And I get this error

> Call to a member function timelogs() on null

About this line of code:

```
Auth::user()->timelogs()->get();
```

I have used the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` in my service

What is going on here?

Comment: `Auth::user()` empty means user is not logged in. are you sure the user is logged in?

Comment: @Saumini Yeah I am sure :)

Comment: @Nicolas hahaha ja echt retarded code ik heb een groot stuk gerefactored maar Laravel is echt wel retarded ik mag ni eens simpele services da ik heb geschreven injecteren in mijn controller...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is (as pointed out in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor) the fact that the Auth middleware is not initialized during the controller construction phase.

You can instead do this though:

```
protected $calenderService;

public function __construct()
{ 
    $this->middleware(function ($request,$next) {        
         $this->calenderService = resolve(CalendarService::class);
         return $next($request);
     });
}
```

Alternative

```
public function controllerMethod(CalendarService $calendarService) { 
    //Use calendar service normally
}
```

Note: This assumes that you're able to resolve the `CalendarService` via the service container.

Comment: This will probably throw an error that the method middleware doesnt exist

Comment: I don't want to do this in my controller btw I want to keep my controllers as clean as possible

Comment: @FrankLucas sorry I thought the first snippet was of the controller. The alternative to this is to inject the `CalendarService` object in the controller method. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `auth()` or `Auth::` in a constructor in the latest versions of Laravel, so you'll need to use this logic directly in the method.

```
public function someMethod()
{
    $timelogs = Auth::user()->timelogs()->get();
```